# Magento 2 Add discount on bundle product on add to cart time

Tags: magento2, cart, price, catalog, bundle-product

I have to add some discount programmatically on the time of bundle product add to cart.

So far I have developed the catalog product plugin `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` function `afterGetFinalPrice` this plugin is worked on the basis of their child product prices so I have used another bundle price plugin `Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price` function `afterGetFinalPrice` but it won't return desired output.

As per the Magento default flow, Magento is applying a discount on its child product but I like to apply the discount on bundle product total price.

Answer (score 0):

You can create following files in your custom extension.

> etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_item_set_product">
        <observer name="bundle_addto_cart_before" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\SetProduct" />
    </event>
</config>
```

File:

> Observer/SetProduct.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SetProduct implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
        if(!$quoteItem->getId() && $product->getTypeId() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE)
        {
            $originalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
            $customPrice = 22.5;
            $quoteItem->setPrice($customPrice);
            $quoteItem->setBasePrice($customPrice);
            $quoteItem->setCustomePrice(null);
            $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(null);
            $quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(false);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This should work.